# SortedList does not find an element it contains while list does

Tags: python, sortedlist, sortedcontainers

In a project I am using a [SortedContainers](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/0.8.4/).SortedList. In the following pseudo-code, I am getting an assertion error:

```
assert custom_class in list(sorted_list) # This does not cause an error
assert custom_class in sorted_list # This causes an assertion error
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't yet create a small runnable example that reproduces the error. `custom_class` is a class that derives from [`abc.ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) and `sorted_list` is a [`SortedContainers.SortedList`](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/0.8.4/). Does anybody have an idea why there could be a difference between the a pure list and a SortedList?

`sorted_list.remove()` also throws an error because `SortedList.bisect_left()` doesn't find the element either...

Thanks!

Edit1:
The issue seems to be occuring here in `__contains__` of SortedList:

```
    def __contains__(self, value):
        """Return true if `value` is an element of the sorted list.

        ``sl.__contains__(value)`` <==> ``value in sl``

        Runtime complexity: `O(log(n))`

        >>> sl = SortedList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        >>> 3 in sl
        True

        :param value: search for value in sorted list
        :return: true if `value` in sorted list

        """
        _maxes = self._maxes

        if not _maxes:
            return False

        pos = bisect_left(_maxes, value)

        if pos == len(_maxes):
            return False

        _lists = self._lists
        idx = bisect_left(_lists[pos], value) # <- This finds the wrong index (in my case 38 instead of 39)

        return _lists[pos][idx] == value # <- The comparison here consequently leads to a falsey value
```

Edit2:
The problem is that the items at position 38 and 39 are of equal value (i.e. their sorting is arbitrary). This breaks the bisec-logic. Does anybody have a good idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Are you really using version 0.8.4?

Comment: The issue might be a type error.

Comment: I am using version 2.3.0 of sortedcontainers. The link might be wrong, sorry. I edited some more infos as well

Comment: Perhaps your `custom_class` implements comparison in an inconsistent manner - there's some set of values where `a < b < c < a`, for example.  Finding an element in a `list` only requires equality to work.

Comment: @jasonharper: The implementation is consistent: `def __lt__(self, other): return self.timestamp.__lt__(other.timestamp)` where timestamp is a number. But SortedList seems to require that the sorting logic of all elements are unequal. I guess this could be considered a bug.

Comment: You say the `==` is false because they're equal?

Comment: That's only consistent if no two objects ever have the same timestamp.

Comment: @jasonharper: Objects can have the same timestamp. But that should just mean that the sorting is arbitrary and not that the `in`-method doesn't work anymore. Or am I mistaken there? I might include a second layer where __lt__ is uniquely defined. That could help!

Comment: @KellyBundy: The two objects are unequal because the selected index is wrong. The error is therefore that the wrong idx is selected.

Comment: But you say "the items at position 38 and 39 are of equal value", so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Anything based on bisection requires an absolutely rigid sort order, or you're going to get different results based on which exact elements get compared.  Your `__lt__()` needs to have comparisons for *every* field that is checked by `__eq__()`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sorry, that might not have been very clear: Their timestamp might be identical, but the other content (and with it the object id) are different. So only from the sorting-perspective, they are of equal value

Comment: @jasonharper: I think you solved it. If you want to collect the points for the right answer, feel free to post one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So your `__eq__` is something other than `__eq__(self, other): return self.timestamp.__eq__(other.timestamp)`?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yes, I am using the basic object equality condition (i.e. the objects should not be identical and not just their timestamps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jsonharper pointed out in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914847/sortedlist-does-not-find-an-element-it-contains-while-list-does#comment123588713_69914847), the problem was that SortedList relies on bisec and therefore requires that all elements are absolutely rigid in their sorting (i.e. if `__eq__` is `False` between to objects, their `__lt__` also needs to be different and uniform). I solved this by keeping tracks of how many objects I have created and used the index of creation if the value that I am actually interested in is equal. This is a quite arbitrary approach and could be swapped for any other rigid sorting.